# Separating question and answerline in exam

Tags: exam

I´m using the exam package and I would like to separate the answerline from the question, so that all answerslines are at the bottom of each page, together.

So far its working using `\vfill` before `\answerline`, but not when the question contains more than one part.

See picture for what I´m trying to achieve.[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, always add a MWE( Minimal Working Example).  It helps us to help you in trying to understand, what you did and saves us from typing and typing.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to accomplish the question using only the `exam` class commands. But, using `tikz` this is rather simple.

Code:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pointsinrightmargin
\bracketedpoints
\begin{questions}
\question The seventh term, $u_7$, of an arithmetic sequence is 28. The tenth term, $u_{10}$, of the same sequence is 37.
\begin{parts}
\part[2]Find $d$, the common difference of the sequence.
\part[2]Find $u_1$, the first term of the sequence.
\part[2]Find $S_{200}$, the sum of the first 200 terms of the sequence.
\end{parts}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (17.5,0) -- (17.5,19) -- (0,19) -- (0,0);
\draw(17.5,4) -- (10,4);
\draw(10,4) -- (10,0);
\node[text width=3cm] at (1.7,18.7) {Working:};
\node[text width=3cm] at (11.7,3.8) {Answers:};
\node[text width=7.1cm] at (13.8,3) {(a)\dotfill};
\node[text width=7.1cm] at (13.8,2) {(b)\dotfill};
\node[text width=7.1cm] at (13.8,1) {(c)\dotfill};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]